# Getting a ProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(); to work, help please

Tags: java

So yesterday with some help from StackOverflow which was appreciated, too bad I can't upvote yet. Well I was able to create a Java program from within a Java program which is one step closer to letting me get to the really hard part of the plan.

So now as the title states I have this code which I'm trying tro get to execute another java program with but so far everything I've tried fails miserable. I have had multiple files now with no errors just nothing happens, nothing opens. Both with  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(); and ProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(); I'm also wondering can I only execute .jar files or can I compile and execute a .java file as well? If so how?
So yes any help with what is going wrong would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit: Updated the code, I'm getting closer to it working it seems. The directories now appear to work. Just I get the error system built in replying it can't find Java -Jar

The code I have so far is available below to read:

```
 import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   public class SelfWrite {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
                      System.getProperty("user.dir"));
         try {
             String newLine = new String(System.getProperty("line.separator"));  
             File f = new File("C:/Users/Powermaniac/workspace/Newfolder/");
             String fileDir = new String (f.getAbsolutePath());
             File j = new File("C:/Windows/System32/java" +  "-jar");
             String javaDir = new String(j.getAbsolutePath()); 
             File tempDir = new File (fileDir); 
             File tempjavaDir = new File (javaDir);
             if (tempDir.exists());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Exists");
             if (tempjavaDir.exists());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Java Exists");
             if (tempDir.exists()) {  
                 String program = new String(fileDir + "UserInput.jar"); 
                 try {
                     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Windows/System32/java", "-jar", program);
                     pb = pb.directory(new File(fileDir));  
                     File temp = pb.directory();  
                     String currentWorkingDirectory = "Current working directory: " + temp.toString();  
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, currentWorkingDirectory);  
                     Process p = pb.start(); 
                     int UserInputExitCode = p.waitFor();  
                     if (UserInputExitCode == 0) {  
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Input Running Successfully!");  
                     }  
                     else {  
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Input Exit Code: " + UserInputExitCode +  
                        newLine + "Something went awry during UserInput.jar execution!");  
                     }  
                 }  
                 catch(Exception e) {  
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Input installation failed!" + newLine +  
                    "Couldn't find \"Java -Jar\" in the Standard Software directory.");  
                 }  
             }  
             else {  
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find the Java -Jar directory!" +   
                         newLine + "Program will now exit.");  
             }  
         }  
         catch (Exception e) {  
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something has gone awry while running the processbuilder class!"); 

         }  
     } 
}
```

Comment: Change JOptionPage.showMessageDialog to System.out.println, in the catch(exception e){ do e.printStackTrace(); so it will print the exception that is happening, after that you can identify the errors and try to move on

Comment: I'm not convinced that `String fileDir = new String(System.getProperty("C:/Users/Powermaniac/workspace/User Input/"));` and `String javaDir = new String(System.getProperty("C:/Windows/System32") + "java -jar");` are going to return valid information

Comment: MadProgrammer, how would I go about checking to see what returns a valid directory or file? I'm only very new to Java programming basically and what I had done in the past has annoyingly been forgotten. Anyway thanks.

Comment: `File fileDir = new File("C:/Users/Powermaniac/workspace/User Input/"); fileDir.exists();` ...

Comment: Also, take the time to understand how `ProcessBuilder` works.  Each parameter to `ProcessBuilder` is a argument that is past to the command.  If you use `C:/Windows/System32/java -jar` `ProcessBuilder` will try and execute it as a single program (which it obviosuly isn't), instead you should be using `new ProcessBuilder("C:/Windows/System32/java", "-jar", ...);`

Comment: Thanks again MadProgrammer. I feel I'm getting closer to fixing it. Just now I have the catch(Exception e) bounce back and say "Couldn't find Java -Jar" So finally getting somewhere atleast.

Comment: See my last comment as to why you got the exception...

Comment: So much comment, so little answer.

Comment: Okay so it worked but again nothing actually happened, no errors nothing it went through perfectly. So I changed the file to the this program I'm using but as a .jar and now I get "Something went awry during UserInput.jar execution!"...

Comment: Guys! One question per a "Question"!

Answer (score 0):

Okay well with some help from some other friendly people I asked I discovered the answer. Although I have a slight feeling I had it before but it didn't work. And I think I know why too. So basically you can open or it doesn't seem you can a runnable .jar if there is no GUI well it seems you can't because nothing appears so there is no indication anything is happening.

Anyway here is the code for anyone else who needs it in the future and finds this post:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "C:/Users/Powermaniac/workspace/Newfolder/BasicGUI.jar");
pb.start();
```